# Procedure to get the parameters and result type of a PostgreSQL stored procedure?

Tags: database, postgresql, stored-procedures, npgsql

What is the procedure to get the parameter and return types of a stored procedure? (Google is of no help :-( ).

Something along the lines of:

```
using (var conn = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(connectionString: c))
        {
            conn.Open();

            using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "\"GetAllDx\"";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                cmd.GETPARAMETERS()????????

            }
        }
```

PostgreSQL 9.5
Npgsql 3.0.5

Comment: you can always query the `pg_catalog.pg_proc` table

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan  I was hoping for a simpler method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT pg_get_function_result(oid), pg_get_function_arguments(oid)
FROM pg_proc
WHERE proname = 'GetAllDx'
```

You may also find this useful (although this query returns more than you've asked for):

```
SELECT oid::regprocedure FROM pg_proc WHERE proname = 'GetAllDx'
```